# JQuery Pop Up Box - Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have implemented a JQuery Pop Up Box that will not work, I was hoping you could direct me. I am still fairly new to the language! I will pop my code below!

---

```
<!-- POP UP HTML -->
<div class="infocontainer">
<div class="infoouter">
<!-- BACKGROUND COLOUR -->
</div><!-- /infoouter -->
<div class="infobox">

<a href="#" class="infoclose"><img class="infoclose" alt="close" src="http://www.doopsdesigns.co.uk/images/socialicons/close.png" width="26" height="26">
</a>
<img class="infoimg" src="#">

<div class="infotext">
<h1 align="center">HELP JASONS POP UP BOX</h1>
</div><!-- /infotext -->

</div><!-- /info box -->
</div><!-- /infocontainer -->
<!-- /POP UP -->
```

---

```
/* POPUPSTART CSS */
.infocontainer{
    display:block;
    }

.infoouter{
    background-color:#222222;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9998;
    float:none;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    }


.infobox{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #f3af4e;
    height:60%;
    width:80%;
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:20%;
    padding:15px;
    z-index:9999;
    float:none;
    }

.infoimg{
    float:left;
    }

.infoclose{
    float:right;
    }   

.infotext{
    left:10%;
    right:10%;
    top:20%;
    bottom:20%;
    padding:10%;
    height:60%;
    width:80%;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    }
/* /POPUPSTART */
```

---

// JavaScript Document

```
$(document).ready(
function() {

    $(".infoclose").click(function() {
        $(".infocontainer").slideRight("slow");

    });
});
```

---

I need it to display on load but hide when the close button is clicked.

I hope I have provided everything... Thanks for any input!

Ta, Jason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dialog widget of JQuery UI. Check out the [documentation here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/). Your code should look like the following and you do not need to worry about closing the popup/modal yourself.

```
$("div.infocontainer").dialog({
    //Add more properties, like modal, closeOnEscape, etc -- refer Documentation
})
```

You can play around more with JQuery UI to add animations and other things to your code.

Answer (score 0):

for simple jQuery you can use `.hide()` of `.slideUp()` function instead of .slideRight

See demo here

https://jsfiddle.net/6a3o86q7/